# Flask Sqlalchemy pagination on a filtered query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to paginate on a filtered query. Here are my models

models:

```
class Lesson(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    thumbnail = db.Column(
    db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default_thumbnail.jpg")
    slug = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("course.id"), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Lesson('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"

class Course(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    icon = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default_icon.jpg")
    lessons = db.relationship("Lesson", backref="course_name", lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Course('{self.title}')"
```

what I want is to display only courses that contain lessons with pagination, so I am using the following query

```
courses = Course.query.filter(Course.lessons).paginate(per_page=6)
```

However, the pagination object from this query returns the same number of pages before filtering, but each page contains only the filtered courses. e.g. page 1 contains only 1 course because the other five courses in this page do not contain lessons. I want to have 6 courses per page **after** filtering.

I hope I was able to explain my problem clearly.

Comment: Hi Omar, can you try this? courses = db.session.query(Course).join(Lesson, Course.lessons).paginate(per_page=6)

Comment: Thanks, Linus. This returned the same results. page one had 1 lesson, page 2 had the same lesson plus another lesson and so on.